# Vb.net Webkit.net error "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception"

Tags: vb.net, browser, webkit, webkit.net

In my application, I was going to use the webkit browser. Unfortunatly, as soon as I downloaded it and placed it in my code, I get this error.
I have it referneced , in toolbox, please help.

Comment: Is this question about C#? Is this question about VB.NET? Is this a question unrelated to a specific language? Anyway it's too generic, check/provide full error message/code. There is a **NativeErrorCode** property, check that code on MSDN and you'll see what's wrong. Did you include all webkit.net **native** dependencies?

Comment: You seem to have downloaded the kit and added it to your toolbox... Is that right? You say you have referenced it. How did you do this?

Comment: @Mych I clicked download on the website and pressed save in the dialog. Then I opened my project and said 'Add Reference' and referenced the WebKitBrowser.dll

Comment: Ok... seems you have done all the steps. I've used this kit several times and I've had no issues. I'm using VS2010. I assume you have tried a restart of VisualStudio. If not try that. When do you get the error?